# What's the meaning of asterisk underscore args as a Python parameter?

Tags: python

In this line

```
def onFaceDetected(self, *_args):
```

from [this](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/dev/python/reacting_to_events.html#python-reacting-to-events) tutorial, what is the meaning of *_args as a parameter to a Python module's method?

I've seen lots of explanations for just an asterisk or just an underscore, but not both.

Comment: The underscore is just part of the name, no special meaning here at all. The `*` syntax doesn't dictate a name, you could use `*foobar` or `*__super_sekret` for all Python cares.

Comment: In this case I'm guessing the author wanted to convey that the extra arguments are being ignored.